# How can I output all apply_filters and do_action?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I would like to output all apply_filters and do_action to give the user an overview of them.

If I use the Code

```
add_filter( 'wpErpOs_testFilter', 'wpErpOs_testFilter_callback', 10, 1 );
function wpErpOs_testFilter_callback( $testVar ) {
$testVar[] = "GM";
 return $testVar;
}
$testVar = array("VW", "Audi");
$testVar = apply_filters('wpErpOs_testFilter', $testVar);
```

then the hooks are displayed in

```
global $wp_filter;.
```

If apply_filters is not called by add_filter, it does not appear in

```
global $wp_filter;;
```

How can I output all apply_filters and do_action, even those that are not called?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I output all apply_filters"? Do you want to display all hooks? Or all registered filters/actions assigned to any hook?

Comment: I'd like to spend all the names of the hooks.
Example: apply_filters('wpErpOs_testFilter', $testVar);
==> Name: wpErpOs_testFilter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply_filters` and `do_action` are **NOT** stored  in `$wp_filter`, **ONLY** `add_filter` and `add_action` are stored in `$wp_filter`

When you call `apply_filters` or `do_action`, core WordPress loops through all of the registered filters or actions (added by `add_filter` and `add_action`), looking for any matching ones, and then executes the associated function.

The only difference being actions which are stored in the `$wp_actions` global var

These are the global vars available for hooks (actions/filters):

`global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $wp_current_filter;`

`$wp_actions` - stores actions that have already been fired with the number of times it was fired, each time `do_action` is called this number is incremented.

You can look at the Query Monitor plugin which does handle tracking of hooks (actions/filters):
https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor

Now with that said, one option you have that you can do, is to add your own action for the `all` action, and then collect and save the filters/actions that are ran yourself.

Here's some sites that talk about this:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/inside-wordpress-actions-filters/

Here's example code of doing this:
https://gist.github.com/bueltge/1000143

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/advanced-topics/#debugging-with-the-all-hook

Comment: Tracing via the "all" hook only works for hooks called with add_filter() or add_action(). Did I understand this right?

Comment: The Plugin Query Monitor shows only hooks called with add_filter() or add_action().

Comment: @Severin no the code for the `all` hook in that example code will store in the db every single time `apply_filters` or `do_action` is called